# Why does this connect npm not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

I am reading Pro Angular JS from Apress by Adam Freeman and it is using the connect node module in the very first chapter.

The node module connect has been installed on my Mac. That is not the problem. The problem is that the book is old and the code is not working.

The code snippet of the server.js file used to get a folders content on a port(5000) is as follows:

```
var connect = require('connect');
connect.createServer(connect.static("../angularjs")).listen(5000);
```

The above file saved as server.js do not run and gives an error.

Comment: what error does it gives ?

Comment: Anyway, for me it works like in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/AWolf81/d1e3213894a16971b071).